# Using resources(?) to dynamically set inner xaml

Tags: xaml

I have some xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

I want to fill this xaml up with some more xaml... that is defined somewhere else:

```
<Border x:Key="TemplateOne">
    ...
</Border>
```

Is there a way of making the StackPanel fill with the Border xaml (Something to do with resources?)?

I have tried this:

```
<phone...>
    <StackPanel>    
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Border x:Key="TemplateOne">
                ...
            </Border>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Resource="TemplateOne">
    </StackPanel>
</phone>
```

But it crashes.

The end result is that I can data bind my resource depending on some variable inside data bound items...

for example:

xaml:

```
<!-- data template for items -->
...
    <StackPanel Resource="{Binding Template">
    </StackPanel>
...
<!--->
```

cs:

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    if( item.type == "sausage" )
        item.Template = "TemplateOne"; // On property changed
    if( item.type == "egg" )
        item.Template = "TemplateTwo"; // On property changed
}
```

**:::EDIT:::**

I've also tried this but it crashes too because StackPanel does not have ContentTemplate as a property.

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="One" TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Height="auto" Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent">
                        <Border Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Width="62" Height="62" Margin="0,0,0,5">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Participants[0].image.thumbnail_link}" Width="62" Height="62" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>

<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource One}">
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a content control where you want to place your template:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource One}">
    <ContentPresenter />
</ContentControl>
```

Then in the phone resources:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="One">
    <Border Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Width="62" Height="62" Margin="0,0,0,5">
        <Image Source="{Binding Participants[0].image.thumbnail_link}" Width="62" Height="62" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```